What is the best way to draw an CV_8UC1 matrix image with Cairo?
I have a matrix image in the format CV_8UC1, i.e. one byte per pixel of monochrome image data. I need to draw this matrix image using Cairo, i.e. to a Gtk drawing area. Speed is critical, as this image will update quickly and I need to redraw very fast.
What is the best/fastest way to draw this matrix image using Cairo? I've tried converting it to a Cairo surface, but I can't find an OpenCV format that I can convert it to that the Cairo surface will accept.
For example, if I convert my matrix image to CV_32S and then create a surface with the format type CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, it will run but the image is very blue, indicating there's a mismatch between data storage types.

"I convert my [CV_8UC1] matrix image to CV_32S and then create a surface with the format type CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24" -- What were you expecting? Are you aware of what is going on there? You start with an array of single unsigned 8-bit values (0-255), let's say L. Conversion zero-extends that to array of single 32-bit values: 000L. Then you tell Cairo to interpret that as RGB32: "each pixel is a 32-bit quantity, with the upper 8 bits unused. Red, Green, and Blue are stored in the remaining 24 bits in that order" Hence, MSB ignored, R and G set to 0, B set to intensity. No wonder it's very blue

I don't use Cairo, but from what I gather from my quick research, there is no dedicated format for grayscale (display, there is A8 but that's only alpha, and used for masks?). Hence, you should aim for RGB24. Since that is 32 bits per pixel, you want to end up with CV_8UC4, which implies using cvtColor and having a dummy alpha channel. Last issue is figuring out the right byte order -- one of COLOR_GRAY2BGRA or COLOR_GRAY2RGBA should do the job (the RGB order doesn't matter, they all get set to same value, it's just a matter of getting the alpha into MSB).

As a side note, using OpenCV from C in 2024 seems a bit masochistic (given that the C API has been deprecated for ages now) ;)

In situations like this awareness of how data is represented in memory and how the CPU interprets this memory is essential.

I don't see the issue either. 8UC1 is 8 bit monochrome. that's all. you have no reason to handle 32S. what you attempted with that conversion is also not what the conversion does. [mre] required.

@DanMašek Yes Dan, I do understand what's happening there, and the blue is not surprising. My point is that I cannot find a common format between Cairo and OpenCV, but was wondering if anyone had a suggestion to work around that.

I understand that I can rearrange the data to fit something that Cairo can work with, but that would really slow me down. The ideal situation would have been to create a Cairo surface directly from the CV_8UC1 data as-is, without further manipulation, but since that's not supported, I was inquiring as to whether anyone had a better suggestion.

"that would really slow me down" -- can't imagine it costing much more than the convertTo, both being just a linear pass copying bytes...


I have a matrix image in the format CV_8UC1, i.e. one byte per pixel of monochrome image data.

That sounds pretty much like CAIRO_FORMAT_A8, except that cairo interprets that one byte as alpha / transparency and not as monocrome color.
Be sure to look at cairo_image_surface_get_stride(). I think cairo requires each row of pixel data to be aligned to a four-byte address.
Put differently: If your image data has a width of 5 pixels, then cairo expects each row to end with 3 bytes of padding.
If these requirements mean that your image data is not in a format supported by cairo, that means you will have to copy the data around to get it into a supported format.

I need to draw this matrix image using Cairo, i.e. to a Gtk drawing area.

Quick example of drawing some bytes to an image surface:
#include <cairo.h>

static unsigned char image_data[] = {
    // First row
    0, 255,
    // Padding
    0, 0,
    // Second row
    64, 192,
    // Padding
    0, 0,
};

static cairo_surface_t *get_source(void) {
    return cairo_image_surface_create_for_data(image_data, CAIRO_FORMAT_A8, 2, 2, 4);
}

static void draw(cairo_t *cr) {
    cairo_surface_t *source = get_source();

    // Fill everything black
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint(cr);

    // Draw the image in white on top
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 1, 1);
    cairo_mask_surface(cr, source, 3, 3);

    // Just because: Also draw it in red
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 0, 0);
    cairo_mask_surface(cr, source, 6, 6);

    cairo_surface_destroy(source);
}

int main() {
    cairo_surface_t *target = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 10, 10);

    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(target);
    draw(cr);
    cairo_destroy(cr);

    cairo_surface_write_to_png(target, "output.png");
    cairo_surface_destroy(target);
    return 0;
}

Output (yes, this only draws a 2x2 monocrome image; once in white and once in red)


Speed is critical, as this image will update quickly and I need to redraw very fast.

Well, where does the data come from? You could for example use cairo_surface_create_similar_image(). That allocates the image data in shared memory (which you can modify with cairo_image_surface_get_data()). This would then (sometimes) allow cairo to avoid a copy of the image data to the display server.
The other thing that comes to my mind: How often does the data change? If it is only changing sometimes, be sure to re-use the same cairo surface. If cairo has to upload the image data somewhere, it can save the upload for later re-use (this is internally called "attaching a snapshot" in the cairo code base).
But basically: I guess I do not know enough to say anything useful about this part of the question.
